# Como fazer um validação tipo if em um conjunto de opções?

Tags: c#

Preciso fazer um `if` onde eu verifique um conjunto de opções pra não fazer um `if` dentro de outro `if` pra verificar se um campo esta preenchido ou não, quero fazer isso com um único `if`.
Ex `if(valr1, valor2, valor3 != "")`

Segue o código

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds.ReadXml(@"\\192.168.0.251\Geral_G.M\Expedicao\XML_ENTRADA\" + txt_chave.Text + ".xml");

txt_fornecedor.Text   = ds.Tables["emit"].Rows[0]["xNome"].ToString();
txt_cnpj.Text         = ds.Tables["emit"].Rows[0]["CNPJ"].ToString();
txt_nota.Text         = ds.Tables["ide"].Rows[0]["nNF"].ToString();
txt_ie.Text           = ds.Tables["emit"].Rows[0]["IE"].ToString();
emissao               = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables["ide"].Rows[0]["dhEmi"]);
saida                 = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables["ide"].Rows[0]["dhSaiEnt"]);

txt_emissao.Text      = Convert.ToString(emissao);
txt_saida.Text        = Convert.ToString(saida);
```

Comment: o código não me parece ser relacionado a pergunta. Consegue elaborar um exemplo?

Comment: Rovann e este código mesmo, porque eu estou lendo um xml, e jogo o valor dentro do textbox, preciso só confirmar se os valores estão vindo do xml e preenchendo o textbox, porque notei que alguns xmls vem sem umas das informações que preciso pra preencher os textbox.

Comment: Poe exemplo tenho recebido alguns xlms sem a data de saída, preciso confirmar isso e dar uma mensagem para o usuario que esta faltando dado no xml lido.

Comment: preciso confirmar as informações nesse bloco que estou recebendo.

Comment: ainda está confuso, pode ser mais específico? quer dizer que as colunas que estão no código (por exemplo "xNome") é que quer validar? Quer saber se **todas** estão preenchidas num único `if`?

Comment: Ricardo isso mesmo, preciso validar as informações que estão vindo do xml.

Comment: me parece mais um problema da lógica que você está usando. Além de que, NF-e fornece os esquemas em XSD, você pode gerar as classes e fazer a conversão direta do xml em um objeto. Do jeito que está fazendo fica mais complicado...

Comment: Entendi, vou melhorar este código sim, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu caso eu sugiro que você criaria uma classe com os campos que represente esse XML e use [DataAnnotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) para as propriedades que não podem ser vazias, seria o atributo `Required`, veja:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome é obrigatório.")]
public string Nome {get; set;}
```

É uma boa alternativa para validação de objetos, pode até implementar a interface `IValidatableObject` no objeto que vai ser validado.

## Usando uma lista

Se deseja verificar vários valores de uma vez, pode usar uma lista para isto:

```
var valores = new List<string>{ "Hi", "casa", "Teste", "ga", "     sa ", null};
```

No método `Exists` você especifica o predicado com a condição, que no caso seria:

```
v => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v)
```

Para verificar se na faixa de valores há algum nulo `null`, vazio `""` ou com espaço em branco `"  "`.

Veja o código completo:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {                
        var valores = new List<string>{ "Hi", "casa", "Teste", "ga", "     sa ", null};    
        var algumElementoVazioOuNulo = valores.Exists(v => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v));
        if (algumElementoVazioOuNulo)
        {
            WriteLine("Sim");    
        }                
        else 
        {
            WriteLine("Nao");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EGIXsj).

Aprenda mais na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Valeu pela explicação.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar os operadores lógicos **&& (e)** ou **|| (ou)**, mas ainda sim terá que fazer a verificação individual de cada item. Pode tentar algo como:

```
if(val1 != "" && val2 != "" && val3 != ""){ ... }
```

Dai é só seguir a tabela da verdade
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]